# Generating a texture and applying it to an object at runtime

Tags: unity, c#, textures, materials

In Unity, I want to generate a texture and apply it to a material. The following method generates a 16x16 Texture2D and applies it. However, my object with the material shows only a gray "default" texture. The texture WILL show if I open it in the inspector and change the filtering mode (Bilinear to Point, etc), but doing this in the script does nothing. Is there something I am missing?

```
public Texture2D myTexture;
public Material myMaterial; //Assigned in inspector

void generateMyTexture()
{
    List<Color> colorList = new List<Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        colorList.Add(Random.ColorHSV());
    }
    myTexture = new Texture2D(16, 16);
    myTexture.SetPixels(colorList.ToArray());
    myMaterial.mainTexture = myTexture;
}
```

EDIT - SOLVED by [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory).
I was missing a crucial last line, `myTexture.Apply();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this adjustment:

```cs
// Put dimensions somewhere they're easy to edit
// without having to change magic numbers throughout the function.
int width = 16;
int height = 16;
int texelCount = width * height;

// Rent a temporary array to hold the colours
// so we don't allocate large structures unnecessarily.
var colors = System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Rent(texelCount);
for (int i = 0; i < texelCount; i++)
{
    colors[i] = Random.ColorHSV();
}
myTexture = new Texture2D(width, height);
// Using 32-bit colours uses 1/4 the memory, for efficiency.
myTexture.SetPixels32(colors);

// Recycle the temporary array we rented.
System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Return(colors);

// Update the GPU copy of the texture, including mipmaps.
myTexture.Apply(true, false);

myMaterial.mainTexture = myTexture;
```

The main change is calling [Texture2D.Apply()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) to update the texture's mipmaps and copy the whole thing into GPU memory where your changes will be visible.

The other changes I showed are just for efficiency - renting a reusable array instead of allocating a new list from scratch each time this is called and resizing it as we fill it up, using 32-bit colours instead of 16 bytes of floating point values, and pulling out the magic numbers for the texture size so it's easy to update this function if your size needs change.

Comment: Thanks. The solution was only `Texture2D.Apply()`, though these optimizations are great to know about about too.

Comment: Do you know if there are any platform limitations to `System.Buffers.ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent(int)`? WebGL hasn't liked my GPU buffering operations which run fine on other builds.

Comment: That sounds like a question you can answer by testing. If it gives you grief, you can always just fall back to garbage collection. Or allocate one persistent array and re-use it if you need to update textures like this frequently.

Comment: True enough! Thanks again.